# Google Forms multiple choice quiz ( mathematical equation in feedback section)

Tags: google-forms

Is there a way for me to put mathematical equation in the feedback(Answer key) of a multiple choice Google Form.

Side not, can I change the score from appearing on the top left corner.

Comment: Welcome to [webapps.se]. Please show what you tried and a brief description of your search efforts as is suggested in [ask].

Comment: solved it , its not possible (using the pdf link instead in the feedback section)